# Mount SMB share on Ubuntu without kernel support [Linux Deploy - Linux on Android App]

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, cifs, smb

I'm trying to mount a SMB share on Ubuntu, but this install is in the Android application Linux Deploy.

This version of Ubuntu doesn't seems to have the cifs module in the kernel.

```
$ find /lib/modules/ -name cifs.ko
find: '/lib/modules/': No such file or directory
```

Is possible to mount a SMB folder in these cases ?

Mount command:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.105/share /mnt/share -o user=my_user,pass=my_pass
```

Error after this command:

```
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Kernel version:

```
$ uname -r
3.4.42-g3a1ecea-00026-g0a0ded4
```

Comment: I don't know if it is impossible, but might be hard. Is transferring files via `smbclient` a viable alternative?

Comment: Linux Deploy runs in `chroot`, so it runs on Amdroid's kernel. You need to build Android kernel with `CONFIG_CIFS`.

Answer (score 1):

As advised by Irfan Latif, i need to rebuild the kernel, so i found another option which is mounting FTP using curlftpfs.

Credits to:

https://linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem